# How to print lines sideways in python?

Tags: python, formatting

I tried to print sorted lines..

```
print accnt, '{}'.format(*file[line][0])#the year 1 .. Accnt.1 2004
print accnt, '{}'.format(*file[line][1])#the year 2 .. Accnt.1 2009
```

the outfile turns out like this:

```
File 1
Accnt.1 2004
Accnt.1 2009
Accnt.2 2001
Accnt.2 2005
```

how can i print it like this:

```
File 1
Accnt.1 2004 Accnt.1 2009
Accnt.2 2001 Accnt.2 2005
```

Thanks!

Comment: you are going to have to share more of your code. how is your data stored? what is your input?

Comment: Perhaps use [prettytable](http://code.google.com/p/prettytable/)

Answer (score 1):

In python 2.x use a trailing comma, in python 3.x use `print(x,end=' ')`:

```
In [165]: l=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

In [166]: for x in l:
     ...:     print x,
     ...:     
1 2 3 4 5 6

In [167]: for x in l:
     ...:     print x
     ...:     
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print every record of each print statement on a line, add a comma to the end of the print statement:

```
print accnt, '{}'.format(*file[line][0]),
print accnt, '{}'.format(*file[line][1])
```

Make sure not to have the comma on the last line, or to use an empty print statement, to print the newline character after each file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want the unpacking operator in there ... `'{}'.format(*"Foo")` will return `'F'`

Comment: You are probably right. I just assumed the original code worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to do parameter expansion, and it doesn't look like you do, this might work.

```
print 'accnt {0} accnt {1}'.format(file[line][0],file[line][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing a little from each of the other (correct) answers here:

While you can use `print foo,` to suppress the newline (in python2.x) and `print(foo, end=' ')` in python3.x, I suggest that you write directly to `sys.stdout`.  This has a unified interface across python versions --

```
sys.stdout.write('accnt {0} accnt {1}\n'.format(file[line][0],file[line][1]))
```

Or more simply:

```
sys.stdout.write('accnt {0} accnt {1}\n'.format(*(file[line]))
```